# Will jQuery Mobile 1.0 alpha 4.1 work with Blackberry OS 5?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

When I test it, I see no CSS or styling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should opt for the recent released jQuery Mobile beta 1 as it supports Blackberry OS 5.

http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/#graded-support

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely go ahead with JQM and BB 5.0,

[See](https://picasaweb.google.com/vikaskanani0/BlackBerry?feat=embedwebsite) my app screen shot, with OS 5.0 css looks little odd but functionally works perfect.